What is 有様[ありさま] meant to express?
I know its grammatical function, but none of the resources I've looked it up in give a very clear-cut definition of the best way to use it. In one, その有様はどうだ is translated as "What a plight you're in", which feels so disconnected with the provided definitions. Can anyone provide a more in-depth view on this word?

有様【ありさま】 is roughly the same as 様子 (state; situation), but in modern Japanese, it's typically used to point out a situation is terrible, shocking, or uncontrollable, often with a cynical overtone. In other words, it's now often closer to "mess" than to a simple "situation".
明鏡国語辞典 explicitly explains this nuance:

ありさま 【有様】
❷《多く「有様だ」の形で》あるきわだった状態や状況を（特に、好ましくないものとして）言う。「落胆を隠しきれない有様で黙り込む」「ちょっと目を離すとこの有様だ」「日々の暮らしにも事欠く有様」

So その有様はどうだ can mean "what a plight" or "what a mess" on its own.
It's still possible to use 有様 to neutrally say "situation/appearance" in highly formal written materials, but this usage of 有様 is becoming obsolete in ordinary text. For example, 湖の有様を絵に描く was probably natural and neutral in the past, but people today would likely wonder if something bad is going on in or around the lake.
Note that there's another word 有り様【よう】, which is used neutrally.
